# Start WSL Ubuntu in specific or current folder on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When installing Subsystem for Linux and Ubuntu from store on his development machine I can switch (or start) to Ubuntu shell by simply

[image]

But the Ubuntu shell start in `/home/techsupp` folder by default. Is it possible to force it to start in same folder than the one I use my `Ubuntu` command?

So in my example I should be in

```
/mnt/h
```

Thank you.

**What I already tried:**

```
H:\>ubuntu help
Launches or configures a linux distribution.

Usage:
    <no args>
      - Launches the distro's default behavior. By default, this launches your default shell.

    run <command line>
      - Run the given command line in that distro, using the default configuration.
      - Everything after `run ` is passed to the linux LaunchProcess call.

    config [setting [value]]
      - Configure certain settings for this distro.
      - Settings are any of the following (by default)
        - `--default-user <username>`: Set the default user for this distro to <username>

    clean
      - Uninstalls the distro. The appx remains on your machine. This can be
        useful for "factory resetting" your instance. This removes the linux
        filesystem from the disk, but not the app from your PC, so you don't
        need to redownload the entire tar.gz again.

    help
      - Print this usage message.
```

I also discover this request on uservoice: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-windows-subsystem-for-l/suggestions/13421103-let-us-right-click-open-bash-here-from-explorer?tracking_code=8a8bc624c72a8336565fcd6d5737d712

Please vote for it.

Comment: This question is on-topic for anyone developing portable software, and needing to drop into WSL without ending up in a different working directory (for example, to compare Linux/Windows compiler output).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I'm on Windows 10 Home with May Update and have Ubuntu 18.04 for WSL installed, I can open the console in any folder with **Shift + Right Click** and selecting the *Open Linux shell here* option

[image]

Comment: If it helps, I've created a registry file you can run, to do this with **Right Click**, instead of **Shift + Right Click**. It also shows the Ubuntu icon in the context menu, if you follow the instructions at the top. https://gist.github.com/Zantier/692fd3e1a28d54708e95921de9b27e67

Comment: This didnt properly work for me. (See @Liu Answer). If you have installed two or more distros (e,g, Ubuntu and Fedora), the default one will get started. You can set the default to Ubuntu by running wslconfig /setdefault Ubuntu. Apparently I had Fedora as default and none of my commands (which I had only installed in Ubuntu)were not working :(

Comment: This works but if I setup default directory in my /.bashrc file, this fails to work. Anyone care to explain why is that?

Answer (score 52):

```
ubuntu run
```

> run <command line>
>          Run the provided command line in the current working directory. If no
>          command line is provided, the default shell is launched.

As far as I can tell the effect is the same as running `ubuntu`, except that it starts in the current directory.

This command works even as a right click open here command in explorer. Adapting from [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/270810/how-to-quickly-launch-a-bash-shell-from-windows-10s-file-explorer/):

- RegEdit to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` and create a new key
- edit `(Default)` to "Open Ubuntu here" or similar.
- add a key named `command`
- edit `(Default)` to `ubuntu run`

Now you have a functional "Open Ubuntu here" right click menu in explorer.

---

The problem I have with `wsl` is that the wsl bash window doesn't have the Ubuntu icon, even if it starts the Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: It is a feature added few months after my original question. Thank you.

Comment: For Windows 10 I put an Ubuntu icon like that: `WSL\command` -> key `Icon` -> Value `"%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2018.817.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc\ubuntu.exe",0`

Comment: Just a quick note, some users may need to replace `ubuntu run` with `wsl.exe`. otherwise it won't find the application.

Comment: Here's a registry file you can run that also lets you right click a folder to open bash in that folder. It also adds the Ubuntu icon to the context menu, if you follow the instructions at the top. The window itself doesn't have the Ubuntu icon, though. https://gist.github.com/Zantier/692fd3e1a28d54708e95921de9b27e67

Answer (score 49):

If you check in Task Manager how the explorer "Open Linux shell here" option opens wsl, you can see that there's a "--cd" option.

[image]

Comment: I find this the most useful (correct?) way to do it from command-line, thanks!

Comment: Good answer and great find!  Based on this, note also that you can start in a WSL path via `wsl.exe --cd "\\wsl$\<distroName>"` (will start in `/`).  I just wish that the `--cd` option was documented in `wsl --help`.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds actually `--` option IS documented, see `wsl --help`: `-- Pass the remaining command line as is.`

Comment: @klapshin I think perhaps you are seeing a linebreak or whitespace where I didn't put one ;-).  I know that the `--` is documented.  I said that I wished `--cd` was documented.  `--cd` is an actual *flag* for the wsl command, not the `cd` command being passed as a result of a `--` (it would require a space after it if so).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds actually I thought `--cd` is just the case, haven't used to all docs terms yet ^_^

Comment: @klapshin No worries.  You are correct that a `-- cd` (with a space) would pass the `cd` command into the wsl session, but the result is that it would `cd`, then exit immediately, as that would be the only command sent to the shell.

Comment: Having `wsl --cd %~dp0 -- bash +x %~n0.sh %*` in a batch is a handy trick to run adjacent shell scripts from windows. That `--cd` flag was just what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 25):

If you use `wsl.exe`, it will start WSL in current directory. But the difference between `wsl` and `ubuntu` is that if you have installed two or more distros (e,g, Ubuntu and Fedora), the default one will get started. You can set the default to Ubuntu by running `wslconfig /setdefault Ubuntu`.

Reference: [1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config

Comment: bash.exe only start in the current directory if the current pwd is on my C:/ drive. Otherwise it starts in my home.

Comment: Thanks, this thing helped with problem when Terminal immediately disappears after start (because I had docker WSL set by default)

Comment: Holy crepes, years later and on WSL2 and this advice still fixed the issue I had!

That `/setdefault` flag completely fixed my broken `bash` command and some other weird upgrade nitpicks!

Answer (score 10):

seems that there is a very simpel solution.

just add the following in Ubuntu configuration in the profiles.json file

"commandline": "wsl ~ -d Ubuntu",

Comment: It doesn't quite answer the OP question, but that was a great tip.  Any idea where `wsl ~` is documented or why it works?  Clearly the `~` is being passed as the commandline to the shell, but it appears to be different from other commandlines.  For instance, `wsl ls` will execute `ls` and exit, whereas `wsl ~` leaves the shell running.  Also, I can't reproduce the same behavior when starting a shell from inside another shell (rather than via `wsl`) either.

Comment: This is what I am wondering. What is special about `~`, and can we use it boot into a different starting directory or for any other behaviour?

Answer (score 9):

The method that has worked for me is to use the Windows Terminal app and configure it to start in the desired location.

Example based on WSL2 and Ubuntu 20.04:

settings.json - Add this line to "Ubuntu-20.04" section:

```
    "startingDirectory": "//wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/home/<username>/"
```

Change <username> to be the name of the user you created on install of Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Good info, but it should be noted that this answer is only applicable to someone using Windows Terminal (and you should edit the answer to reflect that).  The original question did not state that they were using Windows Terminal..

Comment: Good point!  Answer edited to reflect this.

Comment: This is exactly what I came looking for. And why aren't you using Windows Terminal? :) (Seriously, is there something better? cuz it seems pretty cool so far)

Answer (score 7):

**Step 1:** Install [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701)

**Step 2:** Go to the folder you want to open Ubuntu in and open Windows Terminal by right-clicking.

**Step 3:** Go to Windows Terminal Settings and navigate to your Linux distro (in my case Ubuntu 20.04) and check this option.

[image]

Now every time you open Ubuntu through the Windows terminal it will open in that directory.

Answer (score 5):

### Modern solution

1. Install `windows terminal` , from [Microsoft store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk70)
2. Go on settings
   [image]
3. Once you have ubuntu installed you will see it on the list  of profiles and then click on open json
   [image]
4. Open `cmd` , type `wsl` , type `cd`, type `pwd`wslc then copy the path [!
   [image]
5. And put it in the json file, on ubuntu profile, `startingDirectory`
   [image]

**Note:** I have used linux home directory as default directory used by ubuntu. So if you feel like you have other directory you want to use you can replace it with `/home/claranceliberi` to your own prefereble directory

Comment: Alternatively, remove the entry for "source" and change to ``"comandline": "wsl"``, which will run ``wsl`` command in any working directory. E.g., right click -> "Open Windows Terminal" will open ``wsl`` in that directory, and do it properly (will be along the lines of ``/mnt/c/...``)

Comment: @runr Adding "commandLine": "wsl" works but I didn't remove "source" entry, I commented it but that changes is being reverted by Windows Terminal. Will this have any impact?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to check whether  `wsl` is using ubuntu as default or not.
For me it was not. Write the below command on cmd:

`wsl -l`

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfVYv.jpg)

If not then Write `wsl -s Ubuntu-20.04` to set it as default.
Now you can run ubuntu bash from any directory by doing **shift + Rightclick** as shown [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDgJF.png).

Answer (score 1):

if your default terminal is `Ubuntu`, then you can open `Ubuntu` in the current dir easily.

Go to the address bar of the file explorer by clicking on it
[image]

or you can use keyboard shortcut `alt+d` and

there type

```
wt -d .
```

and if the default is `Ubuntu`, it will open `Ubuntu` on that path or you can also type

```
ubuntu run
```

and it doesn't matter if the default terminal is `Ubuntu` or not, it will open `ubuntu` there regardless of anything.

Answer (score 0):

with this little script you can execute every command from the directory your Powershell is currently in. It only works if the drive is already mounted to /mnt/ in the subsystem. It doesn't work with network resources.

```
function tux {$dl = (pwd).Path | wsl eval "cut -c 1 | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'"; $wd = (pwd).Path | wsl eval "cut -d : -f 2 | tr '\\' '/' 2> /dev/null" ; wsl eval "cd '/mnt/$dl$wd' && eval '$args'"}
```

after you have executed it, you can use it like this:

```
tux vim test.txt
```

Comment: by now this seems stupid XD. Back then something like this was needed.
Thanks for the uservoice. It is much better by now.